# Forms Authentication redirects to sign in page constantly

Tags: iis, cookies, forms-authentication

I'm implementing forms authentication on IIS 10. This strikes me as being very easy but it isn't working as expected. As a result i have taken the bare minimum of code from my project and built a test page.

I have a simple application setup in IIS with one page, set as the default (http://[my.site]/mike/intro.aspx), and with forms authentication enabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">            
          <forms cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="intro.aspx" loginUrl="/auth/test.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMS" protection="Encryption" timeout="30" />
        </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The page that does the authentication is in its own app (http://[my.site]/auth/test.aspx) and currently goes to a very simple piece of code that creates the forms authentication cookie and provides a link back to the original application.

```
Partial Class signin
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub signin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim userid As String = "mike"

        Dim formAuthTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userid, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), True, "test data")
        Dim formCookieString As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(formAuthTicket)
        Dim formCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie(".ASPXFORMS", formCookieString)
        formCookie.Expires = formAuthTicket.Expiration
        formCookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
        Response.Cookies.Add(formCookie)

        'Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), True)

    End Sub

End Class
```

I had to comment out the auto redirect as it causes a redirect loop.

I've checked after running this code and the correct cookie is created but when going back to the original page where the forms authentication is enabled, i get sent straight back to the sign in page.

I feel i am missing something obvious but i can't see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to share forms authentication cookie across multiple IIS applications (/, /mike and /auth), you need to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100) Beginners can easily miss the basic IIS concepts, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis as those are not that obvious.

Comment: I suggest you to use [failed request trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see detailed request process, it should clear your confusion.

Comment: Lex Li, your first link solved the issue thank you. The machine key was static for the whole site but i had only configured forms auth for the individual application and not the whole site.